# Does base64 have any characters that can break _SESSION?

Tags: php, base64

I am working on a solution that requires to save the array key as base64 encoded.

While it currently works well, I wonder if base64 (utf-8) encoding have any characters that would break $_SESSION?

Comment: I don't know the specific implementation of $_SESSION in PHP, but the base64 encoding characters are simply A-Z, a-z, 0-9, /, + and =. Only the last three would likely cause you any issues, and presumably that's easy enough to test by putting them in a session variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base64 creates alphanumerical characters and "+", "/" and "=". There are no brackets, therefore there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The $_SESSION is capable of holding arbitrary data as long as they can be serialized/unserialzied by PHP (which most data can). It can handle arbitrary characters since the session data is stored in a file and the file can handle them. In fact you don't even have to call the `serialize/ unserialize` functions yourself, PHP will do that for you.

The question boils down to what characters are allowed as array keys in PHP, and the answer is, if it's a character or an integer, it's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

no. Session will store it as a string of characters . 
Just make sure you have `php-mbstring` extension enabled  . edit your php.ini file to use  `default_charset = "utf-8"`.
and for browser ouput you can use php header function

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

or
you can specify encoding in your html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```